# Inserting data at a particular position in file using fseek() in C

Tags: c

Basically I want to write data to a file at a particular position and don't want to load data in to the memory for sorting it. For example if I have in a file:

**FILE.txt**

> ```
> Andy dsoza
> Arpit Raj
> Karishma Shah
> Pratik Mehta
> Zppy andre
> ```

And i want to insert a contact `Barbie patel` then i will read the first letter in the file after every line , so Barbie should be inserted after Arpit and before Karishma so the file after editing should be:

**FILE.txt**

> ```
> Andy dsoza
> Arpit Raj
> Barbie Patel
> Karishma Shah
> Pratik Mehta
> Zppy andre
> ```

But `fseek` drives me to that postion but dosen't help me insert when i use `fprintf`/`fwrite`/`putc`. It replaces the byte but does not insert before that particular byte.

Loading all the data in to the memmory and sorting it out would not be good if i wold have lot of contacts in future.

Comment: fseek to the end of second line, fread the rest of file to memory (you have to do it), fwrite the new name, fwrite back the rest from the memory.

Comment: You cannot use `fseek()` alone to insert data into the middle of a file.  There is no standard function to insert data into the middle of a file.  Such an operation would require "shifting" all of the subsequent data in the file which necessitates rewriting to the media.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to directly insert into a file without loading it into memory. How you are to manage longer file depends on efficient design approach.

One approach would be to use different files.

Comment: You mean to say 1)loading data into the memory 2) then finding where to insert , if not copy data to other file , 3) then load other contact until end of file

Comment: Well you could name your file such a way that, a.txt contains all names beginning with a, b.txt with b and so on. Of course, initially they will be empty.

Comment: Or use a database, that's what they are for. There are some simple ones (embeddable).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot insert data in the middle of a file. You have to first read everything that's in the file from that point to the end, overwrite and then append what you read.